# Using urlib in a loop

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to write a simple python script that checks the status code of a specific URL and take necessary actions based on the return code. I am using urllib module to achieve this. The issue with this code is that I have different departments defined within a list (I need to iterate over this list inside the urllib) I can't seem to find a way to substitute/insert elements of list in the for loop.

```
import getopt, sys
import urllib.request
depts =  [ 'support', 'edelivery', 'docs']

for dept in depts:
    res = urllib.request.urlopen('https://dept.oracle.com').getcode()
    print(res)
```

I get the below error. Can we actually iterate over a list in urllib module in a loop?

```
#python3 reg_c_with_all.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1350, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1277, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1323, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1272, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1032, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 972, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1439, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/http/client.py", line 944, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 707, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/socket.py", line 752, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reg_c_with_all.py", line 6, in <module>
    res = urllib.request.urlopen('https://dept.oracle.com').getcode()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1393, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1352, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

When I run it individually it returns the response code as expected.

```
    >>> urllib.request.urlopen('https://support.oracle.com').getcode()
    200
    >>> urllib.request.urlopen('https://docs.oracle.com').getcode()
    200
    >>> urllib.request.urlopen('https://edelivery.oracle.com').getcode()
    200
    >>>
```

Comment: Your traceback is different from your sample code, notably that you're missing the "https://" in the traceback's code, causing urllib to error.

Comment: @SuperStormer Thank you for your comment. It was because I didn't post my actual URLs that I am trying to work with. In the traceback error, I just searched and replaced the actual URL with the one that I have included in the above example and missed to add https. I have corrected it now.

Comment: Look like there problem is in your url, because it cannot open in web brower and if I change it to other url then code is working fine

Comment: @Mr.ForExample I have modified the actual post to include the working URLs and it still fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code iterates over the departments but it does not use them to modify the URL. Try using an fstring to insert the value of `dept` in the URL:

```
import getopt, sys
import urllib.request

depts =  [ 'support', 'edelivery', 'docs']

for dept in depts:
    url = f'https://{dept}.oracle.com'
    res = urllib.request.urlopen(url).getcode()
    print(f'{url} => {res}')
```

Output:

```
https://support.oracle.com => 200
https://edelivery.oracle.com => 200
https://docs.oracle.com => 200
```